# Error 404 веб-сервиса

Tags: apache, веб-сервер, 1с, веб-служба, error404

Действовал по инструкции с [Инструкция по созданию веб-сервиса](https://xn----1-bedvffifm4g.xn--p1ai/news/2018-12-03-how-to-create-web-services-using-extensions/)
После открытия страницы http://localhost/UNF/ws/Customers.1cws?wsdl получаю ошибку

```html
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Посмотрел директорию C:\Apache24\htdocs\UNF, но в ней я не нашел файла  Customers.1cws, хотя я действовал точно по инструкции ([Инструкция по созданию веб-сервиса](https://xn----1-bedvffifm4g.xn--p1ai/news/2018-12-03-how-to-create-web-services-using-extensions/)).

Answer (score 1):

Видимо вы не нажали кнопку "Опубликовать", что приведена на рисунке 29, или же указали путь, отличающийся от C:\Apache24\htdocs\UNF, там же.

Comment: а вы у себя пытались запускать? Пришлите скриншот результата (а то у меня начало наклевываться).

Comment: пришлите скриншот результата работы веб сервиса